# what is the sentence structure of the bold sentence in the passage?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice, subjects

> As the US has raised concerns about drones, DJI has increased the
>   kinds of security and data controls it offers its customers. We are
>   not in the business to control data, but we want to give the tools to
>   the operator to say how the data is being stored or processed or
>   transmitted. And those pieces are in place.
>
> ***Fremont fire but someday
>   to have hazardous material sensors on its drones, to know the dangers
>   of a situation before sending in people.*** And maybe one day autonomous
>   drones will go out to a scene to take a look before first responders
>   arrive. Drones are only going to become more important to the agency.
>
> In the next 10 years, it will be as common as seeing fire hose on the
>   back of the engine. You’re going to have a drone in there, because the
>   intelligence gathered by a drone is you know irreplaceable now. It
>   really has become an everyday tool in everyday technology that saves
>   lives, but has also caught up in suspicious between two tech
>   superpowers. Michele Quinn VOA news Fremont California.

The above passage is from VOA news. As for the bold sentence, I can understand its meaning. However, I don't understand its structure. For example, what is the subject and verb of the sentence?

Comment: I am a native speaker, and I have no idea what that sentence in bold type is supposed to mean. If it comes from a text, a line of text was probably dropped. If it comes from speech, please provide a link so that we can try to figure out what was said. In all probability The intended sentence was along the lines of "The Fremont Fire Department does not yet have, but plans someday to have blah blah." Because the VOA is a government agency, it does not pay to expect too much competence from them.

Comment: @JeffMorrowSo, you think that Fremont fire represents the fire department?

Comment: You can hear the audio recording that this was transcribed from here: http://www.qianbi360.com/web/cont/3282.  The transcription has numerous errors.  In this case, the speaker says, "Fremont Fire **hope** someday to have hazardous material sensors on its drones."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about unclear usages from a "sketchy" source.

Comment: @JuhaszThank you! Now I see what is the problem. By the way, it should be shopes someday.

Comment: @HenryWang Yes, what you wrote was missing a verb "hope," and Fremont Fire is a truncation for Fremont Fire Department. It is a common enough truncation in the context of fire departments, but "agency" is not a common substitute for "fire department." Lesson here: if there is audio, please link to it and indicate where the passage lies to give as much **contect** as possible..